# Bibliography: Unwanted indentation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

If I create the pdf out of my LaTeX document, I get for the latest entry an unwanted indentation:

[image]

Can this be somehow avoided? If I work on the document and change things, then sometimes this indentation is there and sometimes not.

Th bibtex-entry:

```
@article{SSI,
  title={Semantic segmentation of aerial images in urban areas with class-specific higher-order cliques},
  author={Montoya-Zegarra, JA and Wegner, JD and Ladick{\`y}, L and Schindler, K},
  journal={ISPRS Annals of the Photogrammetry, Remote Sensing and Spatial Information Sciences},
  volume={2},
  number={3},
  pages={127},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Copernicus GmbH}
}
```

Thank you very much

-edit-

Solution:

```
\usepackage{flushend}
```

has to be changed to:

```
\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Next time I'll add such an example. In this case a friend already gave me a hint why it doesn't work. I added the answer to the question.

Comment: That solution does not make much sense to others when they font even know which document class you are using. I've never seen a problem like this before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by the OP